# Rename links to specific pages (alias) with sharing in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created a website on which various companies/products are displayed. Now the link is quite technical and not pretty. it contains various information to fill the page. an example is:
https://beterbijons.nl/winkel?id=OGnTwRrsdIZ5dJc1WPqzZpjfKWf2

If you're on the website itself, that's no problem. But what I would like is that if you share the link or surf directly to:
https://beterbijons.nl/shopname

so for example:
[https://beterbijons.nl/stichting-britt-helpt](https://beterbijons.nl/winkel?id=OGnTwRrsdIZ5dJc1WPqzZpjfKWf2)

That will take you to that page. However, I have no idea how to achieve this with ReactJs. is there anyone who has experience in this?

I am using React-router-dom and the Router looks like this:

```
 <Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_BASENAME || ""}>
    <Switch>
    
    <div>

    <Route exact path="/" component={ShopPageView}/>
    <Link to="/plaats?naam=:naam"/>
    <Route exact path="/plaats" component={ShopPageView}/>

    <Route exact path="/over-ons" component={BeterBijOnsView}/>
    <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactView}/>
    <Route exact path="/vragen" component={FaqView}/>
    <Link to="/winkel/:id"/>
    <Route path="/winkel" component={ShopSummaryView}/>
    <Route exact path="/winkelmand" component={ShoppingBagView}/>
    <Link to="/product/:plaats/:winkelier/:id"/>
    <Route path="/product" component={ShopProductDetailView}/>
    <Route exact path="/afrekenen" component={CheckoutView}/>
    <Route exact path="/bedankt" component={ThankYouView}/>

    <Route exact path="/inloggen" component={LoginScreen}/>
    <Route  path="/aanmelden" component={SignOnView}/>
    <Route  path="/aanmelden-compleet" component={SignOnCompleteView}/>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you should use `React component` with `some props` in which it returns a `<Link />`

```
 const HomeLink = ({to, ...rest}) => {
       return <Link to={to} {...rest} />
    }
```

Then use it like a   - like  `<HomeLink to="/shopName" exact strict sensitive />`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse! Do you have some documentation what i can read? Because it’s not really clear what to do and how to implement

Comment: @JoppeMeijers check out at : https://reactrouter.com/web/example/custom-link